# Trouble with header files in c++: linker command failed

Tags: c++, c++11, header-files

Apologizing ahead of time for what I'm certain is a very simple problem, but I've been unable to find a solution for this. I'm putting a very simple `C++` project together, but having trouble using a header file appropriately.

The directory structure is below:

```
.
├── mainGraph
│   └── hnsw.cpp
└── utils
    ├── distances.cpp
    └── distances.h
```

The distances header file (`distances.h`):

```
#ifndef DISTANCES
#define DISTANCES

#include <vector>

enum class Metric { Cosine, Euclidean};

double distance(const std::vector<double>& A, const std::vector<double>& B, Metric metric);
double similarity(const std::vector<double>& A, const std::vector<double>& B, Metric metric);

#endif
```

And finally `hnsw.cpp`:

```
#include "../utils/distances.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<double> A = {0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 1.1};
    std::vector<double> B = {0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9};

    std::cout << distance(A, B, Metric::Cosine) << '\n';
}
```

Now, when I actually try to compile `hnsw.cpp` with the following command: `g++ hnsw.cpp --std=c++11` I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "distance(std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, Metric)", referenced from:
      _main in hnsw-ad0e05.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I move the main into the `distances.cpp` file then everything works smoothly. For the purposes of brevity I'm not posting that whole file as it's sizable and I'm fairly certain it's not relevant. If there are any resources about understanding the general process here that would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to build individual object files for later linking, but instead build the whole executable file in one go, you need to specify *all* the participating translation units on the command line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 hnsw.cpp ../utils/distances.cpp
```

The output file will be called `a.out`, unless you also override that name with the `-o` flag.

Usually you would compile translation units separately and link them in a separate step:

```
g++ -std=c++11 mainGraph/hnsw.cpp -c -o mainGraph/hnsw.o
g++ -std=c++11 utils/distances.cpp -c -o utils/distances.o

g++ -std=c++11 mainGraph.hnsw.o utils/distances.o -o myprog
```

You also wouldn't maintain these commands by hand, but stick them into a Makefile, or some equivalent build system. The key point is that you don't need to recompile translation units that haven't changed just because you changed *some* part of your source code.

Comment: This is super helpful. Seems pretty obvious in hindsight, but what doesn't. Last question I've got is just around the order in your second piece. Is there a reason you're compiling hnsw before distances? It seems to be that the reverse would make more sense as hnsw requires distances.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: The two are not related and can be compiled in any order, or in fact in parallel (especially if you have multiple cores). That's precisely what `make` will do for you, for free.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: To be clear, neither translation unit "requires" the other in any meaningful sense. It is only the link that requires *all* of the translation units. (However, both translation units *depend* on the *file* distances.h, so if you change that file, you need to rebuild both TUs. The file forms part of both TUs.)

Comment: Totally makes sense. Thanks for the download. Any chance you know some good resources to get me a better sense of the backend of this whole process?

Answer (score 3):

When you run `g++ hnsw.cpp --std=c++11`, you're telling the compiler to compile hnsw.cpp and link the output with the c++ standard library to create an executable. The linker fails to find the implementation of `distances` because it lives in distances.cpp.

You need to compile both files and link them together. There are many ways to achieve this, but the simplest is to specify both source files when invoking gcc, like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 hnsw.cpp ../utils/distances.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Bummer that you lost the FGIW fight to the person with 305k rep :)